# Using MPAndroidChart in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I am trying to import [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases) in Android studio, I have pasted the jar file into libs folder, And then while trying to Sync I am facing error. Here is my image.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solution. Right click in jar file and hit **add as library** from
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library/16628496#16628496) answer helped friends. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you could solve it. You should accept this answer so that others immediately see it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. download the jar file and use it. I did it and it worked for me.